# Concatenation while ignoring duplicate values

Tags: excel, concatenation

I would like to concatenate a series of cells in a row, EXCEPT where the previous cell contains the same value as the cell in the next column, and add dashes in between.  For example:

Cell A2 = 1234567, Cell B2 = 1234567, Cell C2 = 9845666 and Cell D2 = 5521472.

As B2 is the same as A2, I want to skip it and move on.

I want the output to be '1234567-9845666-5521472', ignoring the repeated value and essentially creating a unique key from each unique value across the cell range within the row.  There may be repeating values through up to seven cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that result with a blend of `IF` and `COUNTIF`, or you can use a user-defined function like the attached. Put it in a module, and call it in your worksheet with `=concatplus(A2:G2,"-",true)`

```
Public Function concatPlus(rng As Range, Optional sep As String = "", Optional noDup As Boolean = False, Optional skipEmpty As Boolean = False) As String
'concatenates a range with the specified separator
Dim cl As Range, strTemp As String

If noDup Then

    Dim newCol As New Collection

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each cl In rng.Cells
        If skipEmpty = False Or Len(Trim(cl.Text)) > 0 Then _
            newCol.Add cl.Text, cl.Text
    Next

    For i = 0 To newCol.Count
        strTemp = strTemp & newCol(i) & sep
    Next

Else

    For Each cl In rng.Cells
        If skipEmpty = False Or Len(Trim(cl.Text)) > 0 Then _
            strTemp = strTemp & cl.Text & sep
    Next

End If

concatPlus = Left(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - Len(sep))

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

=(if(A2=B2,"","A2&" - ""))&(if(or(B2<>A2)&B2<>"",B2&" - ",""))&(if(C2<>B2&C2<>"",C2&" - ",""))&(if(D2<>C2&D2<>"",D2&" - ",""))&(if(E2<>D2&"",E2&" - ",""))&(if(F2<>E2&F2<>"",F2&" - ",""))

Comment: This works as well, but doesn't ignore the duplicate values.  Still useful as a good string concatenations though.  THANKS!